# Finding the index of an array in a two dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, ecmascript-6

I have two arrays. I want to find the index of **currentArr** positions in **originalArr**.
Both the arrays are updated on run time.

```
let currentArr= [[450, 30, "down"],[480, 60, "right"]]
let originalArr = [[510, 60, "right"],[480, 60, "right"],[450, 60, "down"],[450, 30, "down"], [450, 0, "right"]]
```

Can anyone pls help me with this?

Comment: What's wrong with iterating through originalArr and find the entry from currentArr, then remembering the index? Or in other words: please show your current code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the function `map` and the function `findIndex` to look for the matches.

This alternative checks the length as well as each index value using the function `every`.

*I'm assuming the indexes should be at the same position*

```js
let currentArr= [[450, 30, "down"],[480, 60, "right"]]
let originalArr = [[510, 60, "right"],[480, 60, "right"],[450, 60, "down"],[450, 30, "down"], [450, 0, "right"]];

let indexes = currentArr.map(a => originalArr.findIndex(ia => ia.length === a.length && ia.every((e, i) => e === a[i])));

console.log(indexes);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the inner arrays will always be in the same order, you could use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to compare the stringified version of arrays:

```js
let currentArr= [[450, 30, "down"],[480, 60, "right"]]
let originalArr = [[510, 60, "right"],[480, 60, "right"],[450, 60, "down"],[450, 30, "down"], [450, 0, "right"]];

let indexes = currentArr.map(c =>  
                originalArr.findIndex(o => JSON.stringify(o) === JSON.stringify(c)));

console.log(indexes);
```